# implementing pub/sub pattern for a web application

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, sockets, playframework-2.0, client-server

I'm considering several options for implementing pub/sub pattern in my application (Mainly for a 1-1 chat feature but also for others events I want to notify the client). I want it to be cross-browser and hence I can't use `WebSocket` technology alone.

- Atmosphere-play: http://atmosphere.github.io/atmosphere-play/
- socket.io.play: https://github.com/milliondreams/socket.io.play
- web-socket-js: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js
- Implementing my own version of web-socket-js which is essentially using 
  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html

Questions:

1. Which of the options is the preferable?
2. About the last option: Isn't it just using `XMLSocket` and keeping the connection open for server-messages? I mean, is there a real benefit of using a framework here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The hard thing about pub sub is not how you connect to the server, it's how you scale. As far as I know, none of the tech you mentioned there scales to more than one now, you've got to implement that yourself.

So, use akka distributed pubsub. Scales horizontally, just add nodes.

For a comprehensive example of how to use it, along with WebSockets in Play, create a new project in Activator using the ReactiveMaps template, and follow the built in and very comprehensive tutorial. It's available both for Scala and Java 8.

Comment: Thank you. Can you expand about the issue of scaling with akka and what problem is it solving (in terms of my chat feature maybe).